# iOS navigation bar with "tab like" functionality/buttons

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tabs, uinavigationbar

[image]

What would be the best way to make these buttons? I have no problem with the right/left buttons, but this "tab" functionality is eluding me.

I was thinking of adding custom buttons on viewDidLoad like:

```
UIButton *profileBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 100, 30)];
[profileBtn setTitle:@"Profile" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:profileBtn];
```

However, then the buttons stay on the navigation bar until I manually get them off. Surely there is a better/easier way to do something like this? (note that I'm already using the UITabBarController on the bottom of the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html). Switch views by adding both in the first place and hide/show accordingly. If that eats up too much memory create them just in time and remove the inactive one from the superview.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/) on the UISegmentedControl.

Comment: Ahh thanks! The way I have my navigation set up, it was a little bit of a pain to make it work but I got it going now.